# Return NotFound or empty collection

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

If I have an API with a UsersController containing a method that gets a list of users, should I then return an empty collection or a `NotFound("Could not get the list of the users")` when no users where found?

I have read alot about return empty list or null, and the majority of the answers says that I should return what's expected. If a list is expected, an empty list should be returned instead of null..

But does this implies to web api's as well?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The HTTP response code `404 Not Found` represents when a resource (f.i. page) could not be found and indicates that the client has done something wrong.

When the client asks for a list and the list is empty it is not fault of the client, so just return an empty collection with a response code `200 OK`

Comment: So what should i return in this case? An ok with an empty list?

Comment: @JuggernautDev `200 OK`

Comment: I repeat the end of my second paragraph: *so just return an empty collection with a response code `200 OK`*

Comment: @SirRufo: Thank you. How about if I have an endpoint in my API where the client can ask for a user with a specific Id. What should I return if the user are not found with the specific Id? I gues I should return a 404, because the client has entered a "wrong" id that does not exists?

Comment: *indicates that the client has done something wrong*, that's not true. It's perfectly valid for a REST service to return a 404 when not locating an item that has been requested. Lots and lots of REST services do this. It's a mechanism to encode the response message directly into HTTP in an unambiguous way

Comment: @Liam Where did I say the 404 response is not valid for a REST service?

Comment: Webapi is a [REST service](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/apis)? As I said you said, *"[404] indicates that the client has done something wrong"* and as I stated this isn't (strictly) true

Comment: @Liam Please read the Wikipedia [4xx **Client** errors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_errors) - client != REST service - client is the requester - client error => the client has done something wrong

Comment: Yeah, Wikipedia, that's where I get all my technical documentation...[The 404 (Not Found) status code indicates that the origin server did
   not find a **current representation for the target resource** or is not
   willing to disclose that one exists. A 404 status code does not
   indicate whether this lack of representation is **temporary or
   permanent**](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.4). Nothing about error in there. An "Error" is [typically a 500 code](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.6.1)

Comment: Here's [an example of one of the google api endpoints](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors#captions) using HTTP status codes (specially 404) to represent a document/file not being found . Including the text *Check the value of the request's id parameter to ensure that it is correct.* implying that this is not a permanent error, etc.

Comment: @Liam Ok, this discussion will lead to nothing, because I know all those facts and why and when to return 4xx or 5xx. The OP did get my point and that is enough for me. Have a nice day/life